# iterate all possible combination in a huge list using Python

Tags: python, iteration, combinations

I have a huge list in Python over 3000 elements

```
list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ........]
```

I want to iterate all combination in x,y,z variable

here's the code;

```
from itertools import permutations

a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8,.........] #up to 3000 numbers
p = ["Number {x}, number {y} and number {z}"]

for phrase in p:
    for (x, y, z) in permutations(a):
        t = phrase.format(x=x, y=y, z=z)
        print(t)
```

After I run that, the error I encountered:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)
```

Here's the output I expect:

```
Number 1, number 2 and number 3
Number 1, number 3 and number 2
Number 2, number 1 and number 3
Number 2, number 3 and number 1
Number 3, number 1 and number 2
Number 3, number 2 and number 1
and so on......
```

Comment: `permutations` takes an extra parameter to tell it the size of the permutations, otherwise it defaults to the length of the whole thing

Comment: Note, this is going to be almost 27 *billion* permutations...

Comment: For reference, [`P(3000, 3) = 27e9`](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=P%283000%2C+3%29).

Comment: Where are you stuck with the documentation and examples you got when you searched for the necessary tools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from itertools import permutations

a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8] #up to 3000 numbers
p = ["Number {x}, number {y} and number {z}"]
for phrase in p:
    for (x, y, z) in permutations(a,3): #let your code know that you need groups of 3
        t = phrase.format(x=x, y=y, z=z)
        print(t)
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to tell [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) how long a permutation you want, otherwise it attempts permutations of the whole array, so `permutations(a)` will return the same number of values as in the list, which is why you are getting a "too many values to unpack" error. Change:

```
for (x, y, z) in permutations(a):
```

to:

```
for (x, y, z) in permutations(a, 3):
```